# Making a singleton qobject calling QTimer

Tags: qt, singleton, qobject, qtimer

I have a requirement for creating a singleton for QTimer across my program. The problem is that when the QTimer object times out, I get a segmentation fault.

I am currently using qt creator and the debug stack shows the crash on activation() call of the moc_ class for the same on the timeout event.

My current project uses the component architecture template(basically something like a star structure where multiple components communicate via a central component) and I intend to use the class over multiple components.

I originally created the same code on a separate project using the basic template where the code was working.

Hence, this brings me to my question; are QObjects not allowed to exist as singletons over multiple components in a component structure?

Comment: Show your code, I.e. how the singleton is declared, instantiated and used

Comment: It looks like something we can only determine by seeing some code.

Comment: The phrase "singleton over multiple components" needs some explanation. The word "over" has a certain typical use in maths and computer science, and seems to turn the phrase to nonsense. What components are you concreteley referring to? - translation units? shared libraries (a.k.a. dlls)?